# Saga Wait for Status value

Tags: c#, nservicebus, saga, nservicebus-sagas

I have a Saga which should wait for a specific Database-Value to be changed. How do I achieve this?

Example:

```
public partial class OrderSaga : Saga<OrderSagaData>, IHandleMessages<FinishOrder> {
   public void Handle(FinishOrder message)
   {
      Order order=new Order(message.OrderId);
      if (order.Approved) {
         SendMail(order);
      }
   }
}
```

When the bool "Approved" of that Order is true I want to send a mail. But this can take hours or even days. How do I tell the Saga to check again in a few hours?
I am new to Sagas and NServiceBus so the answer might be trivial, but I just did not find it.

Comment: Do you have the ability to make an event be published when an order becomes approved? If so, then subscribe to that event from your saga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defer any incoming message if you're still waiting for another condition to be met. This will apply a time-out to the message and put it back on the bus for future processing.

Depending on whether you're using NServiceBus 4 or 5, the method signature for a deferral will change but let's assume you're on `V4`, you can then do something along the lines of this:

```
if (!order.Approved)
{
    Bus.Defer(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), message);
    //This will defer message handling by an hour
}
else
{
    SendMail(order);
}
```

Comment: No problems, NServiceBus is a bit daunting to use at first, and stupidly powerful as well. A lot of caveats were encountered and overcome in the last couple of months, I'll tell ya :)